# How to get the id attribute of textarea that replaced by TinyMCE editor

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using TinyMCE in my project.I want to get the id attribute of the textarea that is replaced by TinyMCE.Once I get the id of that textarea, then how can I use that id for my jquery functionality like focus,blur,keyup etc. Please give me an example for focus event for that textarea (editor) just by alert something when someone press a key inside the textarea (editor)

I have been stuck with this issue for the last 4 days. So any help in this Please.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a final answer, but too many advices for a comment.

There's a [jQuery package](http://www.tinymce.com/download/download.php) that *"Contains special jQuery build of TinyMCE and a jQuery integration plugin"*.

Some information about event-handling: e.g. the [focus event](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/api4%3aclass.tinymce.FocusEvent). Notice the `tinymce.activeEditor`-snippet.

If you've just one init for one textarea, you should know the [selector](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration%3aselector):

```
tinymce.init({
    // your textarea has the class "myeditor"
    // access with jQuery: $('textarea.myeditor').anyFunction();
    selector: "textarea.myeditor" 
});
```

Maybe it helps you a little. Good luck!

Comment: I have downloaded the jquery package, can you explain which is the main file that I can include in my script as this package has a lot of files.